# Rolling a die - Probability of intersection of two events

Tags: probability, dice

So I have a die, and two events.

$A = \{ \text{''Rolling an even number''} \}$

$B = \{ \text{ 4, 5, 6 } \}$

Then $\text{P}(A \cap B) = \text{P}(A|B)\cdot\text{P}(B) = \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{3}{6} = \frac{2}{6} = \frac{1}{3}$.

Or at least that is what I get? The lecturer says it is $\frac{2}{3}$ at the end but I do not see how. Can someone help?

Cheers

Comment: Maybe your lecturer is wrong? More directly, $A \cap B= \{4,6\}$. So the probability is one-third.

Comment: Your calculation is correct and the answer is $\frac 13$ as you say.

Comment: Perhaps the lecturer meant to say $P(A\mid B) =\frac23$.

Comment: Thanks, all, that is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the question asks

> what is the probability of rolling an even number **or** rolling a number
>   greater than 3?

you should use Inclusion-Exclusion Principle here. For 2 events $A$ and $B$, that is $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$. So we have $$P(A \cup B) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} = \frac{2}{3}$$

Otherwise, if it asks

> what is the probability of rolling an even number greater than 3?

then it is asking $P(A \cap B)$ and your solution is correct.